# bash empty string comparison Issue

Tags: linux, bash

I know i can test a string whether it is empty with `-z` and test a string whether it is non empty with `-n`. So I write a script in ubuntu 10.10:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=
test -z $A && echo "A is empty"
test -n $A && echo "A is non empty"
test $A && echo "A is non empty" 

str=""
test -z $str && echo "str is empty"
test -n $str && echo "str is non empty"
test $str && echo "str is non empty"
```

To my surprise, it output :

```
A is empty
A is non empty
str is empty
str is non empty
```

which I thing it should be

```
A is empty
str is empty
```

Could any Linux expert explain why ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the way Bash command lines are parsed. Variable substitution happens before constructing the (rudimentary) syntax tree, so the `-n` operator doesn't get an empty string as an argument, it gets *no argument at all*! In general, you must enclose any variable reference into "" unless you can be *positively* sure it isn't empty, precisely to avoid this and similar problems

Answer (score 5):

The 'problem' comes from this:

```
$ test -n && echo "Oh, this is echoed."
Oh, this is echoed.
```

i.e. `test -n` without an argument returns 0/ok.

Change that to:

```
$ test -n "$A" && echo "A is non empty"
```

and you'll get the result you expect.

Answer (score 2):

This one will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=
test -z "$A" && echo "A is empty"
test -n "$A" && echo "A is non empty"
test $A && echo "A is non empty" 

str=""
test -z "$str" && echo "str is empty"
test -n "$str" && echo "str is non empty"
test $str && echo "str is non empty"
```

Just $A or $str as empty string will not be a parameter for test and then test status is always true with one parameter (string with nonzero length). The last line works right because test without parameters returns always false.